# How does CT imaging deal with the thickness of materials?

Tags: nuclear-physics, absorption, x-rays, applied-physics, medical-physics

In the medical CT imaging field,  image of an inspected object is obtained through xray projection. xray is attenuated by the inspected object through the formula $I=I_0e^{-\mu t}$. The projection $p$ is defined as $p=\ln\frac{I_0}{I}=\mu t$. Here $t$ is the thickness of the object. In literature, I often see something like "CT imaging display the attenuation $\mu$ of the object ", but there is also an unknown variable thickness ($t$). How does CT imaing deal with the thickness of materials?

Comment: "...but there is an unknown variable thickness (t)..." No, not really. The entire cavity is imaged (everything that hits the imaging screen is imaged). The "variable thickness" is accounted for by the fact that $\mu\sim\mu_{\text vacuum}$ where there "is no thickness." Just like you can "see" where there is low density (low absorption) you can also "see" where there is no density (no absorption). Also, this stuff is probably all explained in a textbook on medical imaging. Have you got a textbook you can look at? The basic principle is called "tomography"

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_transform

Comment: Hi @hft, thanks for your explanation. but I am still confused by how to extract attenuation if one don't know thickness. Is that due to CT scan from many angles and then extract attenuation through reconstruction method like backprojection algorithm

Comment: Another problem is that the initial intensity $I_0$ is also unknow. In the measurement, one only know how many xray remind after it traverses through object, which is the intensity $I$. In this case, we can't calculate the projection $p=\ln\frac{I_0}{I}=\mu t$ if we don't know $I_0$. therefore, do we need to also know the initial intensity $I_0$ before the projection(measurement) in advance in each projection?

Comment: "Another problem is that the initial intensity I0 is also unknow."
No.  In practice, the volume being scanned is almost always larger than the object being scanned, so you're always able to measure the unattenuated x-ray beam

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/745225/2451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to take multiple projections at multiple angles. This is the purpose of the big circular gantry of a CT scanner. It houses the x-ray source and the x-ray detector as they both rotate around the patient, collecting projections from every direction.

Once you have a projection of the attenuation from each direction, then you can use the [Radon Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_transform) to calculate the attenuation at each point in the slice. Tissues which "shadow" each other in one projection will not shadow each other in a different projection and can thus be distinguished.